# Why aren't my pecan nut trees fruiting?

Tags: fruit-trees, nut-trees

I bought a couple of grafted pecan nut trees 2 years ago. They both had small fruit in the last two seasons but I'm yet to taste one as none of them matured. The young fruits all fell during the hot summers.

I wonder if it could be due to the hot summer temperature? The growing zone is 9b/10 and we get top summer temperatures of around 35 Celsius (95 Fahrenheit). They were well watered though so it wasn't thirst.

EDIT: March 2019: I am happy to announce that both trees produced fruit last year. Got about 80 nuts, they are about half the size of store bought pecans. So quite small, but have twice the flavour. : )

Comment: Could you include a photo? For me the plant is still very young. OTOH there could be wrong pruning or other problems.

Comment: Can you also say which variety of Pecan they are, and describe exactly your watering routine, specially at different times of the year - also precisely when the nuts fell off, as in end of summer, beginning of summer, midsummer and did every single one drop?

Comment: Would you like a photo of the nuts, the trees in the summer or the trees in fall? They haven't been prunned at all since I got them. Should I?

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't pay atention to the pecan variety, but it is fairly common : / The watering was deep root watering every couple of days during the summer. And yes every single nut dropped in mind summer. They were about 5cm long (including husk of course) and quite thin when they dropped.

Comment: What size were they? In my experience, it can take 6-8 years until they reliably crop. 6 would probably be the accurate number for grafted trees planted at 3-4'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best thing you can do is contact you're local agricultural extension. For instance, in SC I'd contact the Clemson Ag Extension. Not only do they have great resources online, but you can email them with questions like your.

Most importantly, however, you can take soil samples and send them in. For a small fee, they'll analyze it and tell you what you need to add to amend your soil for the application your using it for. In this instance, growing pecan trees. There are certain macro and micro nutrients you need to get a good yield. It could be there age, it could be they're lacking certain nutrients they need to yield a good crop, or it could be something else. I'd just start with making sure they're getting an appropriate amount of water, sunlight, and nutrients. You can overwater plants as well as under watering them. I don't know about your area, but again I can refer to Clemson's website and it'll tell me how much water per week my tree should be receiving for my area and I compensate for rainfall. Good luck with your trees.